# Best way to keep some custom local changes in GIT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

We have a Rails app that we share with several developers and we are using `git`.

I've made a few changes to the Rails app to match my computer configuration and my own preferences that I don't want to share in the main `GitHub` repository. I wonder what's the best way to keep my custom changes when I am developing while being able to push/pull to stay up to date with the main branch and being able to do pull requests to share the work I am doing on the app.

Comment: Create a local branch for your custom changes. Keep it private; don't ever push it to the canonical remote repo (although you may want to push it to one of your private remotes, for backup purposes). Rebase that branch to `master` frequently.

Comment: What's the nature of these local changes?  Sounds like a properties-overrides file might be appropriate.

Comment: It looks like y'all would have had 3 easy upvotes, had you not accidentally answered in the comments section.

Comment: It's mostly a few configurations files that have to be tracked + some development preference in term of tooling (Like using Pry + Foreman).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a practical workflow for keeping local changes uncommited in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236112/what-is-a-practical-workflow-for-keeping-local-changes-uncommited-in-git)